# Controling size/ scale of additional points in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot in which I am trying to highlight different points along the line. My plot looks like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
X<-c(seq(1:20))
Y<-c(2,4,6,3,5,8,6,5,4,3,2,4,6,6,9,8,9,5,4,3)
Col<-as.character(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5))
value<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,10,NA,NA,NA,20,NA,NA,20,20,10,NA,NA,NA,10,NA,NA)

DF<-data.frame(X,Y,Col,value)


p<-ggplot(DF, aes(x=X, y=Y)) +geom_line(size=.02) +geom_point(col='black', size=.5)+ geom_jitter(aes(color = Col, size = value),position = position_jitter(height = .2, width = .2)) + scale_colour_manual(values=c("red", "violetred","orange",'blue','steelblue'))



p+guides(size = "none")
```

On top of the basic line plot, I have 5 different colored dot possibilities defined by the "Col" column. I also have 2 different size classes I'd like to represent using the "value" column.  My issue is that the default sizes chosen to represent the "value" column is scaled so that the larger size appears too big in the plot in comparison to the smaller size.

Is there a way to manually set the scale so I can control the drawn size of the added points (hopefully make them closer is size to each other)? The final plot should be similar to the one here, only the value=10 points would be only slightly smaller than than the value=20 points.

I've tried using some of the "manual" options, but when I do it always plots the other "Y" column points, which for now are suppressed because of the NAs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same way you manually define the colours for your points using a `scale_colour_` variant, you can define the sizes using `scale_size`.

In this case you can define the range of sizes to use. Adding `+ scale_size(range = c(4,6))` seems to give results that fit your description. You can tweak the size of, and the difference in size between the points by changing the numbers.